# Problem with keyPress in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, events, mozilla

I am using`textarea` to get some inputs. A label shows the updated chars left.
It works fine in IE, but in FF 3.0, after reaching the max limit, it doesn't allow to delete or backspace key.

I am using a javascript function on keypress event of the `textarea`.

the javascript code is

```
function checkLength()
{
    var opinion = document.getElementById('opinion').value;
    if(opinion.length > 50)
        alert("You have reached the mas limit.");
    else
        document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = 50 - opinion.length;
}
```

while on the page, i am using this

```
<label id="limit">50 </label>
<textarea id="opTxtArea" onkeypress="javascript:checkLength();"></textarea>
```

Everything is working fine. The problem arises in FF, when the inputs reach the max limit, the message is displayed, but it doesn't allow to delete or backspace.

Answer (score 0):

You javascript code is wrong

```
function checkLength()
{
    var opinion = document.getElementById('opTxtArea').value;
    if(opinion.length > 50)
        alert("You have reached the mas limit.");
    else
        document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = 50 - opinion.length;
}
```

You were taking the wrong element

```
var opinion = document.getElementById('opinion').value;
```

is now changed to

```
var opinion = document.getElementById('opTxtArea').value;
```

Comment: still it doesn't solve the problem in Mozilla.
After reaching the limit, it doesn't allow backspace or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Tried removing "javascript:"?

Javascript:

```
function checkLength()
{
var opinion = document.getElementById('opTxtArea').value;
if(opinion.length > 50)
    alert("You have reached the max limit.");
else
    document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = 50 - opinion.length;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<label id="limit">50</label>
<textarea id="opTxtArea" onkeypress="checkLength();" maxlength="50"></textarea>
```

In addition, at the line `document.getElementById('opinion').value`, I think you have the wrong ID entered.

Comment: Thx for reply.
That was a mistake.
bust after rectifying the correct id, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, you should remove the `javascript:` prefix in the `onkeypress` attribute, since this serves no purpose.

There are other problems here. What do you actually want to achieve? The alert is very annoying for the user, so I would suggest instead displaying an element on the page to say that the character limit has been exceeded. Also, what do you want to happen when the character limit is exceeded? You could either prevent further input (while not preventing deletion) or do what Stack Overflow does for its comment fields, which is to show a negative number when the character limit has been exceeded but not prevent further input.